# redirect to a controller from block magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I was trying to check few things on a function defined on the block.So if that condition doesn't match, I need to redirect from that function defined on that block to the controller action.

Can anyone please suggest how I achieve this?

Also how can I achieve the same using **objectmanager not using factory method**.

Can you suggest both ways on doing it.

Comment: Can you put some example code that you tried?

Comment: @Qaisar satti How is this duplicate above question is to redirect from controller not the block.

Comment: @sohel I just want the code that redirects from the block, there is no need of my code here. Those that i have tried didn't work

Comment: Redirect from block method is very bad idea. Can you describe your task for determining other way to solve your problem?

Answer (score 6):

```
protected $response;

public function __construct(
   \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $response
)
{
    $this->response = $response;
}

 $this->response->setRedirect('url here');
```

[reference](https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/redirects-in-magento-2/)

Comment: its not working!!

Comment: it is not working. is there any other way to redirect from block?

Answer (score 3):

Do not use the objectmanager. Using Dependency Injections improves the quality of your module by decreasing coupling and thus increasing extendability. This makes better modules and saves time in the future. The last thing we need is teaching people to use dirty solutions because of inadequacy. If we all make high quality modules for Magento 2 it will improve the platform and everyone profits.

Inject the RedirectFactory in your Block constructor:

```
private $redirectFactory;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $redirectFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    )
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->redirectFactory = $redirectFactory
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
```

Call the redirect from somewhere in the Block:

```
    return $this->redirectFactory->create()
        ->setPath('module/group/controller');
```

Answer (score 2):

In your block constructor, inject these two classes: `\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http` and `Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface`

```
protected $redirect;
protected $response;

public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $response,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->redirect = $redirect;
    $this->response = $response;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
```

Use like this:

```
$this->redirect->redirect($this->response, 'catalog/product/view/id/1');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

**filename.php**  file path should be like this.

**vendor/module/Controller/Adminhtml/Actions/Filename.php**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$this->_backendUrl = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface'); 
$url = $this->_backendUrl->getUrl("<router_name>/actions/<filename>");
```

For frontend URL redirect you have to use **\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface**

Comment: I was asking for redirecting from block can you post something related to that

Comment: you can add this code in your block class.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the block class:

```
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http;

class MyCustomBlock extends Template
{
    /**
     * @var Http
     */
    private Http $redirect;
    /**
     * @param Template\Context $context
     * @param CustomerSession $customerSession
     * @param Http $redirect
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        Http $redirect,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    public function customRedirect():Http
    {
        return $this->redirect->setRedirect('/my/fancy/url');
    }
}
```

From the template:

```
<?php  /** @var $block \Vendor\Module\Block\MyCustomBlock */?>
<?php  $block->checkIfCustomerIsLoggedIn()) ?>
```

This works on Magento 2.4.6 . Good luck !